# How to redirect WordPress blog page to root path?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I setup WordPress in our server's different folder so url look like `domain.com/wordpress`

Then I created blog page so my blog url look like do `domain.com/wordpress/blog`

Now i try to change `domain.com/wordpress/blog` to `domain.com/blog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to running WordPress from a subdirectory is as follows:

1) Under **Settings > General**, set **WordPress address (URL)** to:

```
domain.com/wordpress
```

This is the actual location of your WordPress installation. Also set **Site address (URL)** to:

```
domain.com
```

This is what you want the user to enter to get to your site. Save the changes.

2) Copy the .htaccess and index.php files from your WordPress directory into your root directory. Edit the index.php file and change:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

This sends connection requests to the correct directory.

3) Login to your WordPress admin, which should be at **domain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/**. Go to **Settings > Permalinks** and click **Save**. This will update your permalinks.

You should now be running the way you wanted.